# Ensure Excel file is not being used before opening using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am using an interface made with Excel to allow users to concurrently edit a shared data file. To prevent multiple users from editing at the same time I made the following function to do the following:

1. Open the file
2. If the file was opened as a read-only, close the file and re-open until the file is opened as read-write or the maximum number of allowed attempts is crossed.

```
Function OpenTillCanEditC(refpath As String, pw As String) As Workbook
    Dim wbtoopen As Workbook
    Dim maxOpen As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim buttonClicked As Long
    
    maxOpen = 10
    i = 0
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wbtoopen = Workbooks.Open(refpath, True, Password:=pw, ReadOnly:=False)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    While wbtoopen.ReadOnly And i < maxOpen
        
        If wbtoopen.ReadOnly Then
            wbtoopen.Close (False)
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
            Set wbtoopen = Nothing
            i = i + 1
            If i >= maxOpen Then
                buttonClicked = MsgBox("It appears the masterlist is currently being used by someone else. Do you want to retry opening?", vbRetryCancel)
                If buttonClicked = vbRetry Then
                    maxOpen = maxOpen + 10
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                        Set wbtoopen = Workbooks.Open(refpath, True, Password:=pw, ReadOnly:=False)
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                End If
            Else
                On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Set wbtoopen = Workbooks.Open(refpath, True, Password:=pw, ReadOnly:=False)
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        End If
    Wend

    Set OpenTillCanEditC = wbtoopen
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "The password keyed in is wrong."
    Else
        MsgBox "The masterlist found in " & refpath & " cannot be opened. It may be used by someone else or corrupted. If corrupted please open the file manually using Excel."
    End If
    Set wbtoopen = Nothing
    Set OpenTillCanEditC = wbtoopen
End Function
```

OpenTillCanEditC will be used in a sub for updating as shown below:

```
Sub UpdateFile()
    'Try to open
    Dim datawb As Workbook
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim pw As String
    
    filepath = "C:\Folder Containing File\Data File.xlsx"
    pw = "password"
    Set datawb = OpenTillCanEditC(filepath, pw)
    If datawb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "File cannot be opened or is currently in use."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Do functions needed in the workbook here
    
    datawb.Save()
    datawb.Close
End Sub
```

However I keep getting either of the following two errors:

1. When multiple people are attempting to access the file, the OpenTillCanEditC function will still ask for a password even though it is already being keyed in.
2. datawb.Save() will sometimes throw an error stating that the save failed due to multiple users accessing the file.

How do I fix both of these issues to allow multiple users to edit a shared password-protected file using VBA?

Comment: Looks like a usecase for a database instead of an Excel sheet.

Comment: To ① [Workbooks.Open method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) has 2 password parameters `Password` and `WriteResPassword` make sure you know the difference and specified the correct one (otherwise Excel asks for it). • To ② if this error occurs that means something went wrong while opening the file or you need to make sure your computers do never go into powersave mode between opening the file and saving it (otherwise other people can open the file inbetween) and you cannot save it anymore.

Comment: Better use a SharePoint server with a shared Excel file that can be edited by multiple users at the same time (still might run into issues). Best solution use a database.

Comment: For WriteResPassword: what exactly is a write-reserved file? My googling has only stated that it is a save setting that prevents a file from being opened as read and write without the password (none of my datasets are saved as such). Aside from that what does it mean for a file to be write-reserved and based on your comment can a file go into write-reserved mode when being used by someone else?

Comment: No you have to set it `write-reserved` it does not get there automatically. If you haven't then you have run into one of the issues I mentioned in ②. As I said before Excel files are not meant to be opened by many users. Only one user can have write access to a file at the same time. It might go wrong if powersave is enabled or your computer looses connection to the server. So the only proper way is using sharepoint or a better a database. With a normal Excel file and many users you will always run into such issues.